# Bug fixed with four nops in an if(0), world no longer makes sense

Tags: c, debugging, macos, gcc

I was writing a function to figure out if a given system of linear inequalities has a solution, when all of a sudden it started giving the wrong answers after a seemingly innocuous change.

I undid some changes, re-did them, and then proceeded to fiddle for the next two hours, until I had reduced it to absurdity.

The following, inserted anywhere into the function body, but nowhere else in the program, fixes it:

```
if(0) {
    __asm__("nop\n");
    __asm__("nop\n");
    __asm__("nop\n");
    __asm__("nop\n");
}
```

It's for a school assignment, so I probably shouldn't post the function on the web, but this is so ridiculous that I don't think any context is going to help you. And all the function does is a bunch of math and looping. It doesn't even touch memory that isn't allocated on the stack.

Please help me make sense of the world! I'm loathe to chalk it up to the GCC, since the first rule of debugging is not to blame the compiler. But heck, I'm about to. I'm running Mac OS 10.5 on a G5 tower, and the compiler in question identifies itself as 'powerpc-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.0.1' but I'm thinking it could be an impostor...

UPDATE: Curiouser and curiouser... I diffed the .s files with nops and without. Not only are there too many differences to check, but with no nops the .s file is 196,620 bytes, and with it's 156,719 bytes. (!)

UPDATE 2: Wow, should have posted the code! I came back to the code today, with fresh eyes, and immediately saw the error. See my sheepish self-answer below.

Comment: Padding with nop's may fix alignment issues... or perhaps you just need to make sure you're doing a clean build?

Comment: Without seeing the guess, we really can only guess...

Comment: I'm curious, what exactly inspired you to try inserting nops in an if(0) statement? What thought process led you to think that would fix your bug?

Comment: @Chris, I always do that when I'm getting core dumps, just in case it fixes them :-)

Comment: Can you disassemble your program and see if the nops have any obvious effect? The disassembly will probably make the most sense if you compile your program with -O3.

Comment: @sig, wouldn't O3 optimize that if statement out of existence?

Comment: @Pax, you are right.  However, I'm having trouble getting the nops show up at all (even with -O0) on my G4 Mac mini.  I happen to have the same version of gcc (powerpc-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.0.1).

Comment: @rodarmor, I think we're going to need to see the code for further help. Even with stack variables but you can still overwrite memory. We'll understand if you don't want to, but it constrains the way we can help you (and I don't think your lecturer will like seeing those nops in the code :-).

Comment: Just out of interest, what do you mean by "it could be an impostor"? Can you md5sum the executable and compare it against @sigjuice's?

Comment: @Pax I cannot be certain, but rodamor's G5 might have a different executable. "file /usr/bin/gcc" on my system says (for architecture ppc7400).  Here's my md5sum, just in case (56e514baa7dba73b5ded18f9a64c0373  /usr/bin/gcc-4.0)

Comment: @Chris, it was pretty convoluted... Basically though, I had some code that I was sure wasn't doing anything, but removing it broke everything. Since the only thing it could have been doing was changing the length of the code, I replaced it with the most innocuous thing I could think of: if(0) nop

Comment: @Pax, @sigjuice, I was just joking about the impostor bit, but hey, who knows! My md5 is different, but it's probably just benign updates or something. I get: MD5 (/usr/bin/gcc) = 0ce8a1fa01e8914c0a4825c7c67de6c6

Comment: @sigjuice, I just diffed the .s files with nops and without. Not only are there too many differences to check, but with no nops the .s file is 196,620 bytes, and with it's 156,719 bytes. (!)

Comment: I have debugged something similarly frustrating. Sounds like you don't know where the program is failing... you need to find out where it is failing before you can begin to do any debugging.

Comment: Like smcameron suggested in his answer below, I would suspect a problem with the stack.  I've had some really frustrating and surprising things happen after my stack was overflown.  Do you use any recursion?  Allocate any arrays on the stack in a loop?  Try allocating anything large on the heap.

Comment: @rodarmor, I'll check back occasionally but you're putting real constraints on the help we can give until you show us the code. I don't think SO is meant to be a game show :-) My suggestion is to post the code and make all our lives (but especially yours) easier.

Comment: It doesn't have to be THE code. Just come up with a minimal example that still demonstrates the behavior.

Comment: My world doesn't make sense either - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688325/how-can-adding-code-to-a-loop-make-it-faster

Comment: @rodarmor: the size change feels like GCC is deciding not to inline your (a few bytes longer) function with nops; if true, failure when inline likely implies that a caller is clobbering its own stack.

Comment: @pax, heh, you're totally right about the game show bit. Normally I would be less recalcitrant, but it's part of a competition that's run every year.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I came back to this after a few days busy with other things, and figured it out right away. Sorry I didn't post the code sooner, but it was hard coming up with minimal example that displayed the problem.

The root problem was that I left out the return statements in the recursive function. I had:

```
bool function() {
    /* lots of code */
    function()
}
```

When it should have been:

```
bool function() {
    /* lots of code */
    return function()
}
```

This worked because, through the magic of optimization, the right value happened to be in the right register at the right time, and made it to the right place.

The bug was originally introduced when I broke the first call into its own special-cased function. And, at that point, the extra nops were the difference between this first case being inlined directly into the general recursive function.

Then, for reasons that I don't fully understand, inlining this first case led to the right value not being in the right place at the right time, and the function returning junk.

Comment: You could have caught that by turning on compiler warnings, viz. "test.c:6: warning: control reaches end of non-void function". Always a good idea to compile with "gcc -Wall"

Comment: @Hugh, something strange is going on with -Wall. It only warns me about falling out of the function when I've got optimization turned off. -Wall -O0 issues the warning, whereas -Wall -O{1,2,3,4} is quiet. Could it be something about deciding to inline the function?

Comment: Sounds like it might be a bug. Try with the latest gcc version, then go here: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html

Answer (score 15):

Most times when you modify the code inconsequentially and it fixes your problem, it's a memory corruption problem of some sort. We may need to see the actual code to do proper analysis, but that would be my first guess, based on the available information.

Answer (score 13):

It's faulty pointer arithmetic, either directly (through a pointer) or indirectly (by going past the end of an array). Check all your arrays. Don't forget that if your array is

```
 int a[4];
```

then a[4] doesn't exist.

What you're doing is overwriting something on the stack accidentally. The stack contains both locals, parameters, and the return address from your function. You might be damaging the return address in a way that the extra noops cures.

For example, if you have some code that is adding something to the return address, inserting those extra 16 bytes of noops would cure the problem, because instead of returning past the next line of code, you return into the middle of some noops.

One way you might be adding something to the return address is by going past the end of a local array or a parameter, for example

```
  int a[4];
  a[4]++;
```

Comment: All PowerPC instructions are 32 bits.  Four nops would mean an extra 16 bytes.

Comment: Yeah, they're nice instructions. NOP is actually ORI R0,R0,0 (OR register 0 with itself and constant 0).

Comment: Given the crazy differences in the two .s files (see update above), I'm thinking that everyday memory corruption may not be it this time.

Answer (score 3):

Does it happen in debug and release mode build (with symbols and without)?  Does it behave the same way using a debugger?  Is the code moultithreaded?  Are you compiling with optimizations?  Can you try another machine?

Answer (score 3):

Can you confirm that you are indeed getting different executables when you add the if(0) {nops}?  I don't see nops on my system.

```
$ gcc --version
powerpc-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.0.1 (GCC) 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5490)

$ cat nop.c
void foo()
{
    if (0) {
        __asm__("nop");
        __asm__("nop");
        __asm__("nop");
        __asm__("nop");
    }
}

$ gcc nop.c -S -O0 -o -
    .
    .
_foo:
    stmw r30,-8(r1)
    stwu r1,-48(r1)
    mr r30,r1
    lwz r1,0(r1)
    lmw r30,-8(r1)
    blr

$ gcc nop.c -S -O3 -o -
    .
    .
_foo:
    blr
```

Comment: What happens if you make it "if(1)"? I always thought -O0 did absolutely no optimization.

Comment: Does the output of -O0 change when using __asm__ volatile("nop"); ?  (Curious.)

Comment: That's what I though about if(0).  if (1) does emit the four nops, which doesn't surprise me.

Comment: @strager  if (0) {__asm__ volatile("nop") ... } makes no difference to -O0 or -O3.

Comment: @sigjuice does your dungeon master still talk to you?  No honestly you have a mastery and understanding I respect.

Comment: He's complimenting you (in a particularly geeky way, but a compliment nonetheless :-).

Comment: Yeah, I tried it both ways, and the .s files differ wildly. (see above)

Answer (score 2):

My guess is stack corruption -- though gcc should optimize anything inside an if(0) out, I would have thought.

You could try sticking a big array on the stack in your function and see if that also fixes it -- that would also implicate stack corruption.

Are you sure you're running what you think you're running? (dumb question, but it happens.)

Comment: No way a dumb question! One time I was editing on one machine, while compiline/running on another. I was pretty surprised when my changes weren't showing up ;-)

This time though, no such luck!

Answer (score 2):

#### Looks like you will need to put in some hard work and elbow grease

Your problem sounds similar to something I have debugged in the past where my app was running regular ... when out of nowhere it jumped to a different part of the app and the callstack got completely messed up ( however this was embedded programming )!

It sounds like you are spending your time "thinking" about "what should be happening" ... when you should be "looking" at "what is actually happening". A lot of the times the hardest bugs are things that you would never think "should happen".

I would approach the problem like so:

1. Break out your favorite debugger
2. Start stepping through your code and watch the call stack and local variables and look for suspicious activity
3. Make the system fail
4. Focus in to where the system is failing

Focus on iterating your code changes:

1. making code changes that will "make the system fail"
2. running/debugging and watching
3. If it runs fine you are looking/trying the wrong thing and you need to try something else. If you make it fail then you have made progress towards finding the bug.
4. If you don't know where or how the system fails you will not be able to solve the problem.

---

This will be a good opportunity to build your debugging skills. For more help on building your debugging skills read check out the book ["9 rules for debugging"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0814471684).

Here is a poster from the book:

[image: 9 Rules of debugging image]
<sub>(source: [google.com](http://tbn2.google.com/images?q=tbn:BXfm745sxN6oKM:http://www.debuggingrules.com/debuggingrules.jpg))</sub>

---

#### Concrete suggestions:

1. If you think it is the compiler, then run a different platform/OS/compiler.
2. Once you have ruled out the platform/OS/compiler, then try restructuring the code. Look for the "clever" code parts and see if they are actually doing what the code meant to do... maybe the clever solution wasn't actually clever and is doing something else.

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of "Debugging" so kindly referenced above by Trevor Boyd Smith.  He has it right -- the key rules here are #2 Make It Fail (which you seem to be doing okay), and #3 Quit Thinking and Look.  The conjectures above are very good (demonstrating mastery of rule #1 -- Understand the System -- in this case the way code size can change a bug).  But actually watching it fail with a debugger will show you what's actually happening without guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

Break out that one function into a separate .c file (or .cpp or whatever).  Compile just that one file with the nops and without them, to .s files and compare them.

Try an old version of gcc.  Go back 5 or 10 years and see if things get stranger.