# Performance gain from static, const and global variables

Tags: c++

Is it possible to gain performance in C++ by declaring a variable `static`, `const` or making it `global`?

Comment: Compared to what? Variables of what type? How often are the variables used? The answer is: it depends.

Comment: maybe. but don't do that for performance reason

Comment: Compared to defining them inside a function.

Comment: They do different things. You could also improve performance by not running your program.

Comment: In general, that results in completely different semantics. You can't compare the performance of programs that behave differently. When it does *not* affect semantics, it's not answerable: Performance depends on virtually infinitely many factors, and you only gave one. I conjecture that there is zero *noticeable* difference, but in any case you shouldn't worry about it. There are more important things than performance, and when performance becomes your priority there are a billion better ways to improve it than this kind of guess.

Comment: I am serious here, if I have the option, does declaring a variable const static or making it global improves performance?

Comment: If you want a simple answer: No. But be warned, this (simple, extremely general questions about individual language features with no further details) is *not* how one reasons about performance (effectively, i.e. such that the end result is a faster program). *That* is better served by (1) experimentation and (2) understanding the underlying system (your *specific* program, the language you wrote it in, the compiler you use, the operating system it runs on, and the hardware).

Comment: @delnan is serious too. It's impossible to generalize an answer to this question.

Comment: P.S. To get an example of how difficult this can be, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688325/how-can-adding-code-to-a-loop-make-it-faster

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are very unlikely to outperform a function local variable of a built-in type with putting it somewhere else except: If the value of the variable can be computed at compile-time, making it a `constexpr` will be ideal.

- Making the variable `static` may incur a small cost on every call of the function determining if the object was already initialized, especially with C++11 where the initialization is thread-safe. Even if it doesn't need a check, the stack is likely to be in cached memory while a `static` variable is not.
- Making a variable global will increase the chances that it isn't in cached memory, i.e., there is a good chance that it will be slower (aside from adverse other potential like making it a good candidate to introduce data races).
- Making a variable `const` may help if the compiler can compute the value as compile time.

If the variable has a non-trivial type things get more intersting because the initialization cost, e.g., of a `std::vector<T>` is non-trivial. I wouldn't expect a difference between making the objects `static` function local compared to global objects (i.e., I wouldn't make them global; there is no space for global objects anyway). However, making objects `static` introduces the potential that they may be shared between threads. If that is a concern the added locking and serialization probably defeats any potential savings and using allocators using stack-based memory is a better approach to improve the costs (assuming they are small enough to reasonably life on the stack).

Comment: Whether something is in cache has nothing to do with how it's declared at C++ level, only with how (how often, how recently, ...) its address has been used previously. The stack is virtually always in cache because it's virtually always used, yes, but an extensively used global variable will also be in the cache.

Comment: @delnan: OK, so we have: the stack has a high probability to be in the cache, a global variable has a high probablity to be in the cache _if_ it is used often and otherwise a lower probability. If we take these two aspects together I think we can derive that the chances of a global variable being in the cache are likely smaller than a variable on the stack and, hence, there is a higher chance for the access to the global variable to be slower. I used other words but that's what I said. Where do you disagree with the accessment?

Comment: Maybe we're applying different quantifiers here? You appear to average over all possible global variables. I'm assuming the program is cache friendly to start with, because otherwise the cache will be a mess with limited effectiveness anyway. I also have a problem with your wording which, to me, reads as if it's sheer luck (depending on the storage specifier) whether something is in the cache. It's measurable and often easy to predict (though this requires a global view of the code and its memory use), and it's perfectly possible to use for example globals such that they're in the cache.

Answer (score 7):

Performance depends on many factors, you can not assume that simply changing this details would really improve performance.

The best approach to improve performance is to understand the details of your implementation and apply a profiling tool to identify your real bottlenecks.

Most of the time people tend to early optimize code, employing to much effort and making code unreadable on parts that doesn't have much impact on the overall performance of the application.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the assembly code generated by your compiler.

I have observed that a `static const` variable will directly access data in a read-only memory location, rather than allocating on the stack and copying the data.

The performance gain is negligible (almost immeasurable) between a `static` global variable and a global variable.  You would get better results by coding to help the compiler put your variables in registers.

You would also gain performance by setting up your data to fit into a single data cache line.  The processor can fetch the data once into its cache and refer to it there, rather than fetching from external memory.

Of course if you want more noticeable performance gains, reduce your function calls, and branches (jumps).  These cause the processor to reload the instruction cache, which costs more time than accessing data variables from external memory.

You will waste more time debugging if you use global variables.  In general, a program's development cost outweighs its performance.  Some game programs take years to develop but are never executed for years.