# C, are const variables more likely to be on the cache?

Tags: c

so I was reading a book, "Parallel and High Performance Computing in C" that made the claim that const variables and static variables are more likely to get stored on the CPU cache than if it didn't have these keywords, due to it being put at the top of logical memory.
is this true or BS and if so could you explain why or the reasoning behind the special treatment?
I asked Google and couldn't find anything too back up the claim, and asked a C developer i know who had never heard of such a thing.

Comment: More likely *than what*?

Comment: *a book, "High Performance Computing in C"* Who is the author?

Comment: @273K , robert robey &  Yuliana Zamora

Comment: *"due to it being put at the top of logical memory*" - this sounds like BS to me. Where these are being put is totally up to the linker or the developer writing the linker script. Also not sure how it would warrant the caching.

Comment: Can't find such his book "High Performance Computing in C"

Comment: "Where these are being put is totally up to the linker or the developer writing the linker script." could you elaborate on that I've never heard of the linker doing that. & @EugeneSh.

Comment: @273K "Parallel and High Performance Computing"  https://www.amazon.co.uk/Parallel-Performance-Computing-Robert-Robey/dp/1617296465/ref=asc_df_1617296465?tag=bingshoppinga-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=80539328335397&hvnetw=o&hvqmt=e&hvbmt=be&hvdev=c&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=&hvtargid=pla-4584138872097390&psc=1

Comment: Constant data might be placed in a dedicated section (such as `.rodata` in the mainstream toolchains). Then the linker is using either developer-provided or a default linker configuration script to decide where to put this section in the memory. `static` is even weaker, it is just putting the variable in the "regular" `.data` section.

Comment: I doubt he has written "const variables more likely to be on the cache". Please post a quotation of his text.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032885/performance-gain-from-static-const-and-global-variables

Comment: The cache(s) contain items that have recently been used. Const, static, auto, whatever, doesn’t make a difference.

Comment: @gnasher729 aren't the processor caches *blocks* of memory, rather than specific items? I think OP's point is that the variables described are located near to each other in memory.